# decide which files should delete in uninstalling a module in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

Assume That we have two modules which are using blahblah.dll.

when I uninstall one of them, it delete this dll and cause the second module stop working.

is there any way to mention in manifest file which files must delete after uninstall and which shouldn't?

Answer (score 2):

With the DNN 5.x and later manifest format if you register the shared DLL as an assembly and set a version number to it, it is supposed to be smart enough to not remove it if there are other modules that need it.

Now, I would be sure to check this yourself before relying on it.  But otherwise you have the option of going through and creating a third module (Shared Components) essentially that would store the common items.

Comment: @Mitchel Sellers, what if the shared dll is DotNetNuke.dll. I mean, I replace the DotNetNuke.dll as my module is installing, if I uninstall the module, how can I save DotNetNuke.dll from being deleted?